# Convert canvas position to world position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to convert a line a draw on the screen to the position in the world, but I get always the same wrong result.

I register the touch input with:

```
public void OnDrag(BaseEventData eventData)
        {
            RegisterPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        }
```

this is a Vector2

Then I am trying to convert this point to Vector3

```
public Vector3 AimPoint(Vector2 point) {
        return camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(point.x, point.y, 0));
    }
```

But whatever I do I get this result:

> (0.0, 15.3, -8.8)

but the input can be

> (420.1, 422.4) or (66.8, 312.8)

any idea?

Comment: I will tell you that your question is confusing. What does registering a touch have to do with converting pos to world pos? Are you trying to convert a UI component pos under a canvas to world pos? If not, what are you really doing?

Comment: @Programmer I want to draw a line on the screen and get the world position of the points

Comment: What Unity API are you currently using to draw the line?